# Constructing entire functions from functions holmorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus{B_\epsilon(0)}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

Suppose $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a function such that, for any $\epsilon > 0$, $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus{B_\epsilon(0)}$, where $B_\epsilon(0)$ denotes the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centred at the origin. Can $f$ be analytically continued to an entire function?

Besides requiring that its continuation satisfies that $f(0)$ equals its limit, I'm unsure what other requirements are needed.

Comment: Are you famliar with the classification of *isolated singularities?* $z=0$ can be a removable singularity, a pole, or an essential singularity. Analytic continuation at the origin is possible only in the first case.

Comment: Thanks. Assuming $z=0$ is neither of these, say $f(0) = 0$, what could one say?

Comment: *Every* isolated singularity is one of these ...

Comment: Thanks Martin R. Assuming $z=0$ is a removable singularity, it would be great to see an argument that shows that $f$ can be analytically continued to an entire function (assuming this is possible).

Comment: See [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem)

Comment: Great. Thank you!